# Do reference have memory in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am new to C++ and was wondering whether references have memory in C++ .

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{ 
    int a = 55;
    int& b = a;
    int* c = &b;
    int* d = &a;
    std::cout << (c)<<std::endl;
    std::cout << d;

}
```

This outputs:
0077F800
0077F800

If it points to the same address so is reference just another way of accessing the same variable?

Comment: It is not possible to get the address of a reference. The `&` operator gets the address of the referred object. It is also not possible to directly get the size of a reference. `sizeof` on a reference gets the size of the referred object.

Comment: A reference is just another way of accessing a variable, but that doesn't tell you anything about whether they have memory or not. You're confusing the meaning of a reference (which is a C++ language question) with the implementation of references (which is a question about C++ compilers).

Comment: Thank You for answering the question, so in short, &b is just returning the address of the referred object and it doesn't have actual space in the memory?

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
...
int a = 55;
int* c = &a;

std::cout << &a << std::endl;
std::cout << c  << std::endl;
...
```

Both print statements shown here would yield the same memory address. However, there is a difference in their memory usage.

1. `std::cout << &a << std::endl;`
   When we print `&a`, no memory is being allocated - which is also to say that this memory address is not being stored.
2. In the other case, we are explicitly allocating a word of memory on the stack (4bytes on 32 bit systems). This memory is then being used to store the memory address of the variable `a`.

Do have a look the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749954/create-a-pointer-on-the-stack) to understand the difference between allocation a pointer to a variable in stack vs in heap.

Comment: One of the fundamentals to understanding C++ is learning the difference between a reference and a pointer.